# How can I only save edges with the highest and lowest ranks in graph database?

Tags: nebula-graph

There are multiple edges of the same type between two nodes, distinguished by different ranks. How can we only keep the edges with the highest and lowest ranks?

The rank of the graph is defined by time. How can I identify the highest and lowest rank values and their amount?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
match (v1:player)-[e:serve]->(v2:team) 
with max(rank(e)) as max_rank
match (v3:player)-[e2:serve]->(v4:team)
where rank(e2) == max_rank
return count(e2);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).